# How to flip an Android image

Tags: android, opengl-es

All I what to do is change my texture so it facing the other way in the x direction. I tried making the scaleX to be -1 and I also tried making RotX = 1 and angle = 180, but when I changed the values of scaleX or rotate, it also change my positions which I do not want. here is my code for the draw method. is my format wrong?

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {

gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(angle, rotX, rotY, rotZ);
    gl.glScalef(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0]);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexsBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

    if(animation == true){
        PlayAnimations();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the matrix mode to `GL_TEXTURE` and issue a `glScalef(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` before rendering.